# Issue adding inputs/calculations in FOR Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

As the title states, I have a problem adding calculated values into an empty vector, and in the case of a FOR Loop with 1000 iterations, I simply insert the same value 1000 times, instead of different values from each of the 100 iterations. I sifted through the code, line by line, setting i and j to certain values to force stop iterations. See below for my code:

```
# Population Size
N <- 100000
# Iterations per Sample Size
n.sim <- 1000
# Various Sample Sizes
samples.sim <- seq(from=100, to=5000, by=50)

cap.recap.partdeux <- function(N, n.sim, samples.sim){
n <- NA            # sample size
bias.of.est <- NA  # bias of estimator
sd.of.est <- NA    # standard deviation of estimators by sample
l.sim.chap <- NA   # temporary list of estimators to use for later
  # For Loop: Various Sample Sizes
  for(i in 1:length(samples.sim)){
    # For Loop: Iterations per Sample Size
    for (j in 1:n.sim){
      i <- 1:1
      j <- 1:2
      # Catch One
      sim.one <- sample(N, samples.sim, replace=T, prob=NULL)
      sim.one <- as.numeric(sim.one) # Convert to numeric
      # Catch Two
      sim.two <- sample(N, samples.sim, replace=T, prob=NULL)
      sim.two <- as.numeric(sim.two) # Convert to numeric
      # Find Common Elements
      sim.m.two <- intersect(sim.one, sim.two)
      # Amount of Common Elements
      sim.l.m.two <- length(sim.m.two)
      # Calculate Chapman Estimator
      sim.chap <- ((samples.sim[i]+1)*(samples.sim[i]+1)/(sim.l.m.two+1))-1
      l.sim.chap[j] <- list(sim.chap)
    } # End For Loop: Iterations per Sample Size
    # Calculate bias of estimator for each sample
    sum.b.est <- sum(unlist(l.sim.chap), na.rm=T)
    bias.est <- (sum.b.est/n.sim)-N
    bias.of.est[i] <- bias.est
    # Calculate standard deviation of estimator for each sample
    sd.est <- sd(unlist(l.sim.chap), na.rm = TRUE)
    sd.of.est[i] <- sd.est
    # Sample Size
    n[i] <- samples.sim[i]
  } # End For Loop: Various Sample Sizes
  # Return Three Columns and make Data Frame
  Three <- (data.frame(n, bias.of.est, sd.of.est))
  # List of Data Frame with True Population
  Output <- (list(Three, "POP"=N))
  return(Output)
} # End Function
Output <- cap.recap.partdeux(N=100000, n.sim=1000, samples.sim)
Test <- data.frame(Output)
```

Basically, on the line with l.sim.chap[i] <- list(sim.chap), vector l.sim.chap is loaded with repeated values from the first sim.chap iteration, not sim.chap values from each and subsequent iteration.

Comment: Why are you doing `i = 1:1` and `j = 1:2` after you've entered the loop?

Comment: @RichardScriven, I set the i <-1 and j <-1:2 because I wanted to manually debug the code, line by line, before increasing the iteration by another value. when i <- 1 and j <-1, the values are safely stored into the vectors.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I believe you have a point there. Silly me >.<

Answer (score 0):

Removed i <-1 and j <- 1. Code works now. So strange.

```
# Population Size
N <- 100000
# Iterations per Sample Size
n.sim <- 1000
# Various Sample Sizes
samples.sim <- seq(from=100, to=5000, by=50)

cap.recap.partdeux <- function(N, n.sim, samples.sim){
n <- NA            # sample size
bias.of.est <- NA  # bias of estimator
sd.of.est <- NA    # standard deviation of estimators by sample
l.sim.chap <- NA   # temporary list of estimators to use for later
  # For Loop: Various Sample Sizes
  for(i in 1:length(samples.sim)){
    # For Loop: Iterations per Sample Size
    for (j in 1:n.sim){
      # Catch One
      sim.one <- sample(N, samples.sim, replace=T, prob=NULL)
      sim.one <- as.numeric(sim.one) # Convert to numeric
      # Catch Two
      sim.two <- sample(N, samples.sim, replace=T, prob=NULL)
      sim.two <- as.numeric(sim.two) # Convert to numeric
      # Find Common Elements
      sim.m.two <- intersect(sim.one, sim.two)
      # Amount of Common Elements
      sim.l.m.two <- length(sim.m.two)
      # Calculate Chapman Estimator
      sim.chap <- ((samples.sim[i]+1)*(samples.sim[i]+1)/(sim.l.m.two+1))-1
      l.sim.chap[j] <- list(sim.chap)
    } # End For Loop: Iterations per Sample Size
    # Calculate bias of estimator for each sample
    sum.b.est <- sum(unlist(l.sim.chap), na.rm=T)
    bias.est <- (sum.b.est/n.sim)-N
    bias.of.est[i] <- bias.est
    # Calculate standard deviation of estimator for each sample
    sd.est <- sd(unlist(l.sim.chap), na.rm = TRUE)
    sd.of.est[i] <- sd.est
    # Sample Size
    n[i] <- samples.sim[i]
  } # End For Loop: Various Sample Sizes
  # Return Three Columns and make Data Frame
  Three <- (data.frame(n, bias.of.est, sd.of.est))
  # List of Data Frame with True Population
  Output <- (list(Three, "POP"=N))
  return(Output)
} # End Function
Output <- cap.recap.partdeux(N=100000, n.sim=1000, samples.sim)
Test <- data.frame(Output)
```